# How can i connect to sql server from my android application?

Tags: android, eclipse, sql-server-2008, database-connection, connection-string

I'm developing an android application. I need connect to sql server. I wrote a code for test connection but i get this error :

> java.sql.SQLException: Network error IOException: Permission denied

- I checked connection string.
- I closed firewall for 1433.
- I tried configured Sql Server tcp and remote access settings

but i still get the same error. What is my mistake?

My environment:

- Sql Server 2008 R2
- Eclipse
- jtds

My Code is:

```
try
{  
  Class.forName("net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
  **Connection conn=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://192.168.1.33:1433/Android_Deneme;instance=CASPER\\MORTY;user=ugur;password=1234");**
  String sql="insert into tablo1(ad,yas) values(?,?)";
  PreparedStatement prepared = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
  prepared.setString(1, "ali");
  prepared.setInt(2, 30);
  prepared.executeUpdate();
}
catch(Exception e)
{
  e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: are you trying to connect android app to sql server database directly?

Comment: Yes, on the local network. I have to do this way for my project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to add the following permission to your application manifest file.

```
<manifest>
    .....
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    .....
</manifest>
```

Comment: Thank you i did this but now i get this error:

java.sql.SQLException: Network error IOException: /192.168.1.33:1433  Connection refused

Comment: you getting network error again? Can you put ur sql statement?

Comment: Yes i'm getting network error again. There is a Sql State on the error line. It is : 08S01 Is that what you want?

Comment: Are you trying to connect over the wifi? If so check that your phone is also on the wifi network. Or it could be firewall issue. so it is no more an android issue.

Comment: Yes, over the wifi. I did these things already. I connect the phone on the network. I closed firewall but i still get the same error. I think the problem is about sql server. I'm missing something about remote access but what. I coudn't find.

Comment: Are you able to ping the above address from some other machine?

Comment: Yes, i can. I can also connect to sql server from another pc.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I fixed the problem. The problem was about sql server configuration.